# Magento 2 product list page pagination not working

Tags: magento-2.1, category, pagination

I am using Magento 2.1.5 and and on category listing page i have 48 products but its default display 12 products but not showing the pagination.
how to solve it ?

default value for product is set 12 per page. Has any one have this issue?

Comment: hi @Utsav, got the solution? facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Please check if all the products are in stock/enabled and there visibility.

Comment: yes all products are enable / instock and visible.. but only on category pages pagination not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue for pagination in Solwin_Freego theme.

Soldout lable module will overwrite listing page thats why the pagination not working.

it should help some one...

Thanks.